# org.gradle.api.plugins.Convention deprecated and org.jetbrains.kotlin.android is using it

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

im fixing a android project and when i added kotlin i started to get this problem.

```
The org.gradle.api.plugins.Convention type has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.7-rc-4/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecated_access_to_conventions
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.logConventionDeprecation(DefaultConvention.java:392)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.getPlugins(DefaultConvention.java:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.internal.CompatibilityConventionRegistrarG81.addConvention(CompatibilityConventionRegistrarG81.kt:14)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.android.configurator.GradleConventionAddKotlinSourcesToAndroidSourceSetConfigurator.configure(GradleConventionAddKotlinSourcesToAndroidSourceSetConfigurator.kt:20)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.android.configurator.CompositeKotlinAndroidSourceSetConfigurator.configure(KotlinAndroidSourceSetConfigurator.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.android.KotlinAndroidSourceSetFactory.getOrCreateConfiguredKotlinSourceSet(KotlinAndroidSourceSetFactory.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.android.KotlinAndroidSourceSets$applyKotlinAndroidSourceSetLayout$2.execute(KotlinAndroidSourceSets.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.android.KotlinAndroidSourceSets$applyKotlinAndroidSourceSetLayout$2.execute(KotlinAndroidSourceSets.kt:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.android.KotlinAndroidSourceSets.applyKotlinAndroidSourceSetLayout(KotlinAndroidSourceSets.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.android.KotlinAndroidSourceSets.applyKotlinAndroidSourceSetLayout$default(KotlinAndroidSourceSets.kt:20)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AndroidProjectHandler.configureTarget(AndroidProjectHandler.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin$Companion$dynamicallyApplyWhenAndroidPluginIsApplied$2$1.execute(KotlinAndroidPlugin.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin$Companion$dynamicallyApplyWhenAndroidPluginIsApplied$2$1.execute(KotlinAndroidPlugin.kt:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.CollectionFilter$1.execute(CollectionFilter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer$2.execute(DefaultPluginContainer.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer$2.execute(DefaultPluginContainer.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.withId(DefaultPluginContainer.java:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin$Companion.dynamicallyApplyWhenAndroidPluginIsApplied$kotlin_gradle_plugin_common(KotlinAndroidPlugin.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin.apply(KotlinAndroidPlugin.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin.apply(KotlinAndroidPlugin.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:265)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPluginWrapper.apply(PluginWrappers.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPluginWrapper.apply(PluginWrappers.kt:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:285)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:169)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_dqskbdk8qqmtz8nwqu4ruz6lj.run(C:\Users\joaoj\Documents\GitHub\AgroLucros2020\app\build.gradle:110)
    at
```

is indicating the line following as the error

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

Here is the  gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
android {
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.x.x"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdk 34
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 31
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    namespace 'com.x.x'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res {
                srcDirs 'src\\main\\res', 'src\\main\\res\\layout\\Manejo'
            }
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.2.1"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:8.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf:com.google.firebase.firebase-perf.gradle.plugin:1.4.2'
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.vinodpandey:dotsindicator:2.1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:12.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:6.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:3.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.5.0"

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.5.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.5.0"

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:truth:1.5.0"

    // Espresso dependencies
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.5.1"

    // The following Espresso dependency can be either "implementation",
    // or "androidTestImplementation", depending on whether you want the
    // dependency to appear on your APK’"s compile classpath or the test APK
    // classpath.
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.5.1"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

I tried following the link about the deprecated code, but at least in my build.gradle i couldnt see it anything that could be the problem, also, gradle 8.7.-rc-4, android gradle plugin 8.3.1, java 21, kotlin is the latest one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying your plugins using the old syntax, and doing it at the end of your build script. That isn't going to help your chances of getting it to work.

Use [modern practice](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) and apply your plugins using the `plugins` block:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
```

You will probably also have to change your root `build.gradle` to the same:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.23' apply false
}
```